# Webpack server not updating changes to symlinked files

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I am using npm workspaces which I have setup like this (the comments are not actually in the `package.json`):

```json
{
  "name": "game-engine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start --workspace=test"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "test",             // My test game
    "packages/core",    // The game engine core classes
    "packages/common",  // Optional common classes
    "packages/input"    // Optional input classes (mouse/keyboard)
  ]
}
```

I then have webpack setup like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * @type {import('webpack').Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Test Game',
    template:'./src/public/index.html'
  })],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
};
```

then all of the `package/*` look like this:

```json
// All the packages extend tsconfig.base.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}

// tsconfig.base.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

When I start my dev server, webpack builds the files. However, whenever I make changes to the files such as rename/move/delete/etc. or add/remove parameters from a method/function webpack seems to keep the old version information. In order for my changes to be seen I have to restart my webserver. I think it has something to do with how npm workspaces work but I am not sure.

In my root I have `node_modules/@engine/core` which is a symbolic link to the actual packages, this is the same with `common` and `input`. I am not sure if webpack is not handling this correctly or not. Is there a way I get get webpack to see the changes and update it's internal cache or whatever it does to display changes?